# Matrix cannot be indexed with

Tags: matrix, indexing

I'm trying to write a code on image compression.

```
I = imread('cameraman.bmp');
I = im2double(I);
T = dctmtx(8);
dct = @(block_struct) T * block_struct.data * T';
B = blockproc(I,[8 8],dct);
```

whenever i try to execute the above line, I encounter with an error as

```
error: matrix cannot be indexed with .
error: called from
    @<anonymous> at line 1 column 45
    blockproc at line 135 column 6
```

please help me with this.
thanks.

Comment: What language or environment is this?

Answer (score 3):

> @anonymous> at line 1 column 45

It wrote that the error in the position of "block_struct.data".

The error happens because your block_struct is a matrix (for example, [1 2; 3 4]) and it is not callable object (in other words, "block_struct." is forbidden).

Try to delete ".data".

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue resolved by correcting multiplication calculation.
Assuming here 'data' is a variable that is multiplied to  **block_struct**

Change **block_struct.data**  to **block_struct * data**
In Matrix calculation * is used instead of dot notation.

hope it helps.
JSH

Comment: Hi. When I read your answer, it is hard to pick out the syntax change. Can you format the answer?